# Who is in control of community bot?

Tags: discussion, answers

Is it automated? It seems to have lost its mind. I quote a series of texts to make my point. The very clever may have noticed I do make an unreferenced claim (that happiness is less under control than the virtue of integrity) but it is so obvious that I doubt it's easy to find a reference, and I did make it clear that it was my opinion, unlike everyone else does. Any help?

[What does it mean to truly fail at life?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/99026/what-does-it-mean-to-truly-fail-at-life/99288?noredirect=1#comment292310_99288)

Comment: first they came for my questions, then they came for my answers??

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369272/resolving-community-user-and-share-feedback-issues-in-review-queues